# SQL use one or multiple sql tables?

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I just need an idea not some code.

An app exists which allows  user to build multiple playlists filled with songs.
Every playlist is using an `sql table` to save the songs in database.This  gives the opportunity to the user to make changes on each playlist asynchronously(for example remove or add new songs).

But here comes the problem when i want to search all the database tables(-> playlists) for some songs i have to join all these tables and this is slow.

**Pros**->Allows user to do edits on each playlist asynchronously

**Cons**->Slow on searching,Big database file

> Second Way

One other way i am thinking of doing this using one table to keep everything from all playlists but then the user can't add or remove songs asynchronously on every playlist(it has to wait->*the table is locked*),but the search is only in one table.

**Pros**->database is smaller cause no duplicate songs exist,search is fairly easy

**Cons**->user can't add or remove songs asynchronously on every playlist(the actual problem i don't want)

> **The problem is:**

Is there some way to have both speed and asynchronously....?

Comment: How slow would joining be with your expected datasets?

Comment: @OJKrylow If each playlist contains 200.000 songs and 20 playlists exists + 20 libraries which are like playlists i think it will blow up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you go with the classic many - to - many approach.

You can have one `songs` table and one `playlists` table. A song can be part of many playlists and a playlist can contain multiple songs. To model this, you create a relation table, that maps a song to a playlist - basically you just need the song id and the playlist id. You can add additional info to the relation as well (for example the position of the song in the playlist, etc.)

When querying, you would need to join the 3 tables together most of the time (depending on your search logic). You can try and be smart about it by putting the correct database indexes and maybe even preparing some views to speed things up.

I am not exactly sure why you think that you actually make asynchronous changes to the database. Internally, SQLite executes all commands in a serial fashion, one after another. The key to avoiding deadlocks and such is keeping your transactions as short as possible. Since inserting, updating and deleting from those tables should be really fast, I don't think you should be worried about making concurrent changes to playlists at all.

Answer (score 2):

You are not creating tables for every playlist your users are building are you?

I'd say you need three tables:

```
Songs
| id | Artist          | Name                    |
| 1  | Michael Jackson | Billie Jean             |
| 2  | Rick Astley     | Never gonna give you up |
| 3  | Led Zeppelin    | Stairway to heaven      |

Playlist
| id | Name               |
| 1  | My first playlist  |
| 2  | My second playlist |

Playlist songs
| playlist | song |
| 1        | 1    |
| 1        | 2    |
| 2        | 2    |
| 2        | 3    |
```

Comment: yes i do i create a table for each playlist i build.I have a table for all the playlists created so i can retrieve them on loading and a table for each playlist.

Comment: Which means that you have to update all your queries for every playlist your users create. You don't want that, really.

Comment: what happens if i delete for example Michael Jackson from songs table?The 'Playlist songs' table will be notified or i have to do this manually?I mean i have to change the indexes of songs column in table 'Playlist songs'?

Comment: You can configure that behaviour by adding `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` statements to your foreign key definition. https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions

Comment: You never update the indexes in a table. id=1 is always Billie Jean. If you remove this song, the table just starts at 2.

Comment: thanks for answering.I see the second way has a lot of complexity,for example if i delete a song then it has to figure out Playlist songs table but also it has to figure out if it has to delete it from Songs table or keep it because and other playlists are referencing to it,madness :)